# Shifting the integration variable in loop integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, feynman-diagrams, regularization

We know that, in four dimensions, shifting the integration variables is valid only for convergent and logarithmically divergent integrals. If we employ a hard cutoff $\Lambda$, is it permissible to shift the integration variable for, say, a linearly or quadratically divergent scalar field 1-loop integral? Is it acceptable to shift the integration variable for a divergent integral where a hard cutoff regularization scheme has been employed?

Comment: Once a cutoff is in place, the integral is convergent (for finite values of the cutoff), and the variables can be shifted. Mark that the shift will modify the (cutoff-dependent) limits of the integration, which may seriously complicate evaluation of the integral.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you explain that about the limits in more detail (or maybe give an example in, say, a scalar field theory model)?

Comment: No need to introduce field theory for an example. Just take any integral you like, such as $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (x+a)^2 dx$ for example. This integral is divergent. Introducing a cutoff gives $\int_{-\Lambda}^{+\Lambda} (x+a)^2 dx$. If we now shift the integral over $-a$, we get $\int_{-\Lambda+a}^{+\Lambda+a} x^2 dx$. So the limits of the integral change, which will influence the final result.